# When to use React.Fragments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fragment

I just learned about React Fragments.

I understand that fragments are slightly more efficient by creating less tree nodes and makes it cleaner when looking at inspector, but then why should we ever use  as containers in React components? Should we always just use React.Fragments in our components?

Will using fragments make it more difficult for styling? (I'm not sure as I haven't tried it out myself yet).

Comment: `React.Fragments` is a very new feature added only in React v16.2.0, so beware of your React version when trying to use this. I don't think styling would be that much of an issue though, it simply remove the need to always nest separate components with a `<div />`

Comment: If you want to return more children but you don't really want to surround them with a parent element could be an example. No it won't be harder for styling...

Comment: Thanks. As I see it so far, if I don't need the `<div />` container then I could easily just use fragments interchangeably without much difference  (assume I'm using the right version).

Answer (score 5):

In most common practices, React only allows to render single <> element. If you want to render multiple elements, you could surround them by `<div></div>` or `<span></span>`.

Fragment situation example:
One of the most important usage of Fragment is in the `<tbody>` tag (as stated in the official website's example [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)), in a situation that you wanted to render multiple `<tr/>` rows in an element, you might find that it's impossible to wrap them around `<div>`, since inside the  tag you can only have `<tr/>` element!

Well, in the other situation, I recommend to always use single element render, unless you have to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `React.fragments` when you have to get props, like, `<React.fragments key={1}><\React.fragments>`.
If you don't need props, you can use `<> <\>`.

Answer (score -3):

Using `<></>` is just bad practice IMO.

I recommend only using `<div></div>` when you **require** the children to be placed inside an parent element. Otherwise it is pointless/excess html that is just not required.

For example we have a classname associated with the Div element.

```html
<body>
  <div classname="people-group-1">
    <h1>Hello Shippers</h1>
    <h1>Hello Matey</h1>
    <h1>Hello Pal</h1>
  </div>
  <div classname="people-group-2">
    <h1>Hello Mucka</h1>
    <h1>Hello Geeza</h1>
    <h1>Hello Dude</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

I don't recommend using the following example as the Div elements serve no purpose apart from a readability perspective.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Shippers</h1>
    <h1>Hello Matey</h1>
    <h1>Hello Pal</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Mucka</h1>
    <h1>Hello Geeza</h1>
    <h1>Hello Dude</h1>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- No different to--->

<body>
 <h1>Hello Shippers</h1>
 <h1>Hello Matey</h1>
 <h1>Hello Pal</h1>
 <h1>Hello Mucka</h1>
 <h1>Hello Geeza</h1>
 <h1>Hello Dude</h1>
</body>
```

If you need to return multiple elements which dont need a parent, you can use this approach.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

const names = ['Shippers', 'Matey', 'Pal', 'Mucka', 'Geeza', 'Dude']

export const Headers = () => (
  <Fragment>{names.map(name => <h1>{`Hello ${name}`}</h1>)}</Fragment>
)
```

Then you can import it to the renderer of wherever like.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Headers } from './Headers'

export const Body = () (
  <body>
    <Headers />
  </body>
)
```

This will transpile into

```html
<body>
 <h1>Hello Shippers</h1>
 <h1>Hello Matey</h1>
 <h1>Hello Pal</h1>
 <h1>Hello Mucka</h1>
 <h1>Hello Geeza</h1>
 <h1>Hello Dude</h1>
</body>
```